# why mongo doesn't replace OR stage by SORT_MERGE stage when the entries are already sorted

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a collection with the following two indexes: `{ tags: 1, views: 1 }` and `{ author.username'': 1, views: 1 }`

I am looking for a way to get the result of the following query in the most optimized way

```js
searchArray = ['exam', 'ple', 'dot', 'com']
collection.find({
    $or: [
        { tags: { $all: searchArray } },
        { 'author.username': { $in: searchArray } }
    ]
 }).sort({ views: -1 }).limit(10).explain()
// it takes ~0.05ms with ~150 000 entries
```

With the previous request the query planner does not give a suitable solution because of the SORT stage.

however if we remove the $or each request individually is very fast and without SORT stage.

```js
searchArray = ['exam','ple','dot','com']
collection.find({
  tags: { $all: searchArray }
}).sort({ views: -1 }).limit(10).explain()
// it takes ~0.002ms with ~150 000 entries
```

```js
searchArray = ['exam','ple','dot','com']
collection.find({
  'author.username': { $in: searchArray }
}).sort({ views: -1 }).limit(10).explain()
// it takes ~0.003ms with ~150 000 entries
```

so in individual queries we don't have a SORT stage, which means that the data is already sorted using the index, so why doesn't the query planner use the SORT_MERGE stage instead of the OR stage?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are really lucky that a `SORT_MERGE` is happening. Usually when you apply a RANGE query (your `$in` or `$all`) that uses the first part of your index, a `SORT` cannot happen using the second part of the index. Because each branch of the B-tree of the index you are exploring are not sorted between each other. The `SORT_MERGE` is here to actually merge those branches of the B-Tree into one result.

In your case, the problem with the first query is that you want two completely different indexes to `SORT_MERGE` between each other. Which is definitely not possible. The `SORT_MERGE` can only happen if you use the same index multiple times.

So, what I would advise in your case is to actually create an index only on the `views` field. At least it should speed up the sorting.